# function, return, 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: qgis, python

I'm still trying to write a python plugin to create an input file for an urban climate model out of three shape files. Now I stumbeled into another problem, that I think is an easy one, but I just can't see whats wrong. 
I wrote a little function to get me the path and file name of the current project file (as I want the result file of my calculations to be called like the project file by default).

```
def projectfilepathname(): 
    # function to extract the file path and name of the current project file
    qgis.mainWindow().statusBar().showMessage("Getting project name and path")
    prjfi = QFileInfo(QgsProject.instance().fileName())
    path_name = []
    if prjfi:
        path_name.append(str(prjfi.absolutePath()))
            filename = str(prjfi.fileName())
            if filename.count(".") > 0:
              path_name.append(filename.split(".")[0])
            else:
              path_name.append(filename)
            path_name.append(prjfi.fileName())
    else:
            path_name.append(r'C:\Users')
            path_name.append(r'test')
    return path_name
```

I call the function by

```
currentprofile = self.projectfilepathname
```

but that doesn't seem to work. At least I get an error for the next line

```
currentprofile_dir = currentprofile[1]
```

telling me 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.
Maybe I'm wrong, but I have the impression that the function is not called, but its name is saved to currentprofile. Whats wrong?

Comment: Your indentation levels, at least how you posted them here, are not quite right. You also should take a look at [the python style guide ] (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It well help others to read your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning currentprofile to the function named `projectfilepathname`:

Change this:

```
currentprofile = self.projectfilepathname
```

to

```
currentprofile = self.projectfilepathname()
```

You should also change the method def to `def projectfilepathname(self):`

Comment: That did it. I thought it was something like that. I tried self.projectfilepathname() before, but without "self" in the functions definition and got another error. Thats why I removed the brackets. Thank you!